# PHP: Using POST on a dynamic page redirects me to index.php and does not post the values

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to get a guest book to work using PHP. I have managed to make it function, the thing is that I don't want the guest book to be in my index.php. I want it to be on a dynamic page, index.php?=guestbook for instance.

The problem is that when I put the code on another page rather than index.php the thing that happends when I fill out the fields and press the submit button, I get redirected to index.php and nothing is submited to my database. This all works fine as long as the code is in the index.php.

My first question is: What is causing this?
Second question: How do I get the code to function properly eventhough I have it in index.php?=guestbook?

Thanks in advance!

I am using xampp btw.

See below for the code:

```
    <html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Guestbook</h1><hr>

<?php

mysql_select_db ("guestbookdatabase") or die ("Couldn't find database!");

$queryget = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY id ASC") or die("Error witch query.");

$querygetrownum = mysql_num_rows ($queryget);

if ($querygetrownum == 0)
 echo "No posts have been made yet. Be the first!";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($queryget))
{
 $id = $row ['id'];
 $name = $row ['name'];
 $email = $row ['email'];
 $message = $row ['message'];
 $date = $row ['date'];
 $time = $row ['time'];

  if ($id%2)
   $guestbookcomment = "guestbookcomment";
  else
   $guestbookcomment = "guestbookcommentdark";


   echo "
    <div class='$guestbookcomment'>
     <div class='postheader'>
     <b>Posted by $name ($email) on $date at $time</b>
     </div>

      <div class='message'>
      ".nl2br(strip_tags($message))."
      </div>
    </div>
   ";}

echo "<hr>";

if($_POST['submit'])
{
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $date = date("Y-m-d");
 $time = date("H:i:s");

  if ($name&&$email&&$message)
  {
   $querypost = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES ('','$name','$email','$message','$date','$time')");
   echo "Please wait... <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2'>";
  }
  else
   echo "Please fill out all fields.";
}

echo "
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>

Your name: <input type='text' name='name' class='name' maxlength='25' ><br> <br>

Your email: <input type='text' name='email' class='email' maxlength='35'><br><br>

<div class='your_message'>
Your message:<input type='textarea' name='message' class='messagetextarea' maxlength='250'><br><br>
</div>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post'>

</form>

";

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite? If so, can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: what file is this that you're showing? index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The action property of your form should be the same as the name of the file where the code is in. :) You create a guestbook.php, for example, but the action still is 'index.php'. Hence the problem. You send the POST data to index.php but there's no code to process it.

2) The query string doesn't affect the form. Only the filename.

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Oh, It's so obvious now that you point it out! This does indeed solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your form's action parameter to:

```
index.php?=guestbook
```

instead of just index.php?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem resides on the server end than the victim to your problem is .htaccess (mod rewrite);

Otherwise, what do you really mean by this line of code?

```
 echo "Please wait... <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2'>";
```

< meta > refresh tag requires location to be mentioned where the redirect otherwise according to you refreshes the current page..

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://stackoverflow.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm assuming the file you're showing is `index.php`

Second, don't use `index.php?=guestbook`. URL parameters work within a key => value structure. In you're case you've only defined the value and no key.

Try using `index.php?page=guestbook`. this way, in your `index.php` file you can do something like:

```
if($_GET['page'] == 'guestbook') {
    // ... your guestbook php code.
}
```

Then try setting your forms `action` attribute like this: `action="index.php?page=guestbook"`.

Third, I'm going to assume that you have mysql connection code that isn't shown here. If not, take a look at [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Fourth, **NEVER** use unescaped data in a SQL query. You **MUST** escape your data to protect your database from being destroyed. Take a look at this wikipedia article which describes SQL Injection in greater detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
Then take a look at [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to learn how to prevent it with PHP and MySQL.

Fifth, don't use `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2'>` for redirect. Use PHP's [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect users, like this:

```
header('location: index.php');
exit(); // be sure to call exit() after you call header()
```

Also, just so you know, you CAN close PHP tags for large HTML blocks rather than using `echo` to print large static chunks of HTML:

```
<?php
// ... a bunch of PHP
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">

Your name: <input type="text" name="name" class="name" maxlength="25" ><br> <br>

Your email: <input type="text" name="email" class="email" maxlength="35"><br><br>

<div class="your_message">
Your message:<input type="textarea" name="message" class="messagetextarea" maxlength="250"><br><br>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">

</form>


<?php
// ... some more PHP
?>
```

Comment: As pointed out by Bored Elf the problem was that I didn't change the form action when I moved the code. I am still quite new at this so these silly problems still happen unfortunately.

First:
Indeed.

Second:
I am using index.php?p=... and $GET_. I made a typo in my post here.

Third:
Yeah, I just didn't include it here.

Fourth:
Thanks! Still haven't learnt the ins and outs of security so I will definatly read those articles.

Fifth:
Didn't know you could do that, so thank you for the tip.

Thanks for all the pointers!

Comment: Great tips indeed, jordanstephens. :D